# About log information when using Java Adapter of MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

When I use Java Adapter with MFPF 7.1 and generate the log as below code.

```
@Produces("application/xml")
public String hello(){
    //log message to server log
    logger.info("Logging info message111...");


    return "<title>Hello111 from the Java REST adapter</title><body>Hello from the Java REST adapter</body>";
}
```

But When deploying the adapter in mobilefirst Studio and calling the adapter, I failed to find the log information.

Another question is that I found AnalyticsAPI is not valid in MFPF 7.1. How can I generate log information into the analystics console?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your log in INFO level; you need to ensure that the server is running in reporting mode that will display INFO-level messages in its messages.log.

From the Servers view, double-click on MobileFirst Development Server and change the logging level.